# Which preposition to use with “sentiment” to describe an opinion on a topic?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, expressions, prepositions

Which preposition(s) can be used with “sentiment” in the following context?

> The general public’s sentiment **[preposition]** environmental issues changed over time.

I am aware of the following options, but am not sure which to use, whether any is appropriate, or whether this list is exhaustive:

- sentiment *about* an issue
- sentiment *towards* an issue
- sentiment *on* an issue
- sentiment *concerning* an issue

As far as I understand *sentiment for* would express something close to a feeling of pity, rather than the more general concept of emotions people express in relation to a topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general all the prepositions are valid with the word. In the given context, *towards* seems more popular. Also, ***regarding***, which I would prefer over all other alternatives.

Comment: Yes - ***regarding*** definitely rings most true to me as well.